# Field of $4$ elements is not isomorphic to a subfield of a field with $8$ elements .

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields

To  prove  that  a  field  of  $4$  elements  is  not  a  subfield  of    field  of  $8$  elements .

How  to  start  the  proof  I have  no  clue.

Thanks for  any  help.

Comment: Hint - a (finite) field extension $E$ of the base field $F$ of $4$ elements is a vector space over the base  field $F$. In particular, it has a basis.

Comment: Different hint: what are the orders of the elements in the multiplicative groups of nonzero elements?

Comment: To clarify my hint above - if $V$ is a vector space of dimension $n$ over $F$ (the finite field of $4$ elements), what  is the cardinality of $V$?

Comment: @peterag  :  It  is  $4^{n}$ . Now  $?$

Comment: Can one solve $4^n = 8$? (with $n$ an integer)

Comment: @peterag :  No. So  that  is the  contradiction  $?$

Comment: If $F$ were contained in $E$ (the field with $8$ elements), then $E$  would be a finite dimensional vector space over $F$, and you would have to be able to solve $4^n = 8$. Got it?

Comment: @peterag  :  Yes , I  got  that .  That  is  what  I  meant  in  my  previous  comment  .

Comment: Great - To explain Daniel's hint - the non-zero elements of $F$ are a cyclic group of order $3 = 4 -1 $, whereas the non-zero elements of $E$ are a cyclic group of order $7 = 8 -1 $. So it is impossible for $F^*$ to be a subgroup of $E^*$.

Comment: @peterag  :  Oh ,  thank  you  so  much.

Answer (score 3):

Let $E$ and $F$ be fields with $4$ and $8$ elements respectively. The set of units of $E$ and $F$, say $\mathcal{U}(E)$ and $\mathcal{U}(F)$ are groups under the product. These groups are of order $3$ and $7$, since $E$ and $F$ are fields.

Suppose that $E$ is a subfield of $F$, then $\mathcal{U}(E)$ is a subgroup of $\mathcal{U}(F)$ and, by Lagrange's theorem, $3$ divides $7$, which is a contradiction.